# LINQ ToListAsync expression with a DbSet

Tags: c#, linq, async-await, entity-framework-6, ienumerable

I have coded a C# MVC5 Internet application, and have a question about using the `.ToListAsync` LINQ expression.

Here is my code that works in an Index action result:

```
IEnumerable<IMapLocationItem> mapLocationImageGalleries = await db.mapLocationImageGalleries.Where(m => m.userName.Equals(userName)).ToListAsync();
IEnumerable<IMapLocationItem> mapLocationVideoGalleries = await db.mapLocationVideoGalleries.Where(m => m.userName.Equals(userName)).ToListAsync();
IEnumerable<IMapLocationItem> mapLocationItemsCombined = mapLocationImageGalleries.Concat(mapLocationVideoGalleries);
```

I am wanting to create a service function for the above code. Here is what I have coded:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<IMapLocationItem>> GetAllMapLocationItemsFromUserName(string userName)
{
    IEnumerable<IMapLocationItem> mapLocationImageGalleries = await db.mapLocationImageGalleries.Where(m => m.userName.Equals(userName)).ToListAsync();
    IEnumerable<IMapLocationItem> mapLocationVideoGalleries = await db.mapLocationVideoGalleries.Where(m => m.userName.Equals(userName)).ToListAsync();
    IEnumerable<IMapLocationItem> mapLocationItemsCombined = mapLocationImageGalleries.Concat(mapLocationVideoGalleries);
    return mapLocationItemsCombined;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error   17  'System.Linq.IQueryable<CanFindLocation.Models.MapLocationItems.MapLocationImageGallery>' does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync' and no extension method 'ToListAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<CanFindLocation.Models.MapLocationItems.MapLocationImageGallery>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The exact same code works fine in the Index action result, yet not in a service method. Why is this and how can I get this working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have the correct using statement? `using System.Data.Entity`

Answer (score 74, accepted):

As noted in the comments, add `using System.Data.Entity` (under the Entity Framework package) to get the `QueryableExtensions`.

For .NET Core, these methods are under [`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions)

Comment: Just to add: QueryableExtensions is in Entity Framework package.

Comment: Any idea about what this should be in .NET Core?

Comment: @mnwsmit Looks like it should be under [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions)